# Does adding a folder to your classpath add sub-folders?

Tags: bash

I am doing this in a script:

```
if [ -d $SERVICE_HOME/../config ]; then
  CLASSPATH="$SERVICE_HOME/../config:$CLASSPATH"
fi
```

And the /config folder has sub-folders in it also, will files in the subfolder be added to the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the content of the folder.

#### class files in folder

The hierarchy below the folder is a one-to-one mapping to the package structure of your classes.

E.g. the file `./org/example/MyClass.class` will be used for the class `org.example.MyClass`.

#### jar files in folder

These files will be ignored, because a jar file has to be explicitly added to the classpath.

E.g. `CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${SERVICE_HOME}/mylib.jar`

#### some notes

- A classpath should *normally* only appended. With the addition of an element on the beginning you may incidentally overwrite another class.
- In bash you may also use this shorter construct for appending:
    `CLASSPATH+="$SERVICE_HOME/../config"`

Comment: the files are not jars, but resource files like .properties and log4j.properties.